# How to write a subprocess.Popen line of code

Tags: python

I have used

```
    self.session.open(MoviePlayer, sref)
```

to start playing a file with MoviePlayer in my python 2.6 code,
I have been advised that i should use

```
    subprocess.Popen()
```

but am unsure how I should convert the above line to use this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what th self.session.open stuff is, but here is a simple example
of how to use subprocess:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['echo', 'run', 'your', 'command'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate('')
print '==== exit code:', p.returncode
print '==== stdout:'
print out,
print '==== stderr:'
print err,
```

Save that to a file and run it from the command line in a Unix-like system.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html has more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to run system command with python

```
import os
os.system("date")
```

or

```
import os
f = os.popen('date')
now = f.read()
print "Today is ", now
```

or if you want to use subprocesss:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("command1")
subprocess.call(["command1", "arg1", "arg2"])
```

==

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l", "/etc/passwd"])
```

==

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("date", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
print "Today is", output
```

==

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-l", "/etc/fstab"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print "*** Running ls -l command ***\n", output
```

==

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "10", "www.siyahsapka.org"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print  output
```